# RSA / DSA implementation in the Forth language

Tags: rsa, pgp, dsa, forth

I need to develop a [PGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) implementation for a custom [Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29) kernel, and I was wondering if anyone could give me pointers as to where I could get an [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29)/[DSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm) implementation in (any) Forth to use for the project.

I prefer source code with a flexible license that allows me to use it for whatever I desire. This will save me a lot of hours in coding my own RSA/DSA algorithm which will then take days to debug and mature into something stable.

In addition, where can I get and RSA/DSA implementation in pure assembly for the x86 architecture 32/64 bit, preferably in Intel syntax for [NASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netwide_Assembler) as an alternative to the Forth code. I can simply use the assembler code to write a native word into the kernel (since the kernel is 64 bit assembly language) to perform the functionality of the algorithm.

Comment: did you ask on comp.lang.forth? they are usually helpful there when they take a break from the infighting :^)

Comment: The powers that be are once more delusional. How can this question atract "opiniated answers and spam"? This is not "finding a tool" but ask for help for an all too specific programming problem.